# In ruby on rails, how could I convert a time in ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone to Month, Date, Year?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In ruby on rails, how could I convert a time in ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone to Month, Date, Year.
For example, I have following time:

```
Fri, 08 May 2015 22:54:31 UTC +00:00
```

What I need is like:

```
05/08/2014
```

Comment: You can look into this for different date formats http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime

Comment: Follow the link http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime

Comment: [Add a date/time format](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats) and use Rails' `l` helper (shortcut for `I18n.localize`) in your view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)** like this:

```
 > t = Time.now
 #=> 2015-05-11 12:47:32 +0530 
 > t.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
 #=> "05/11/2015"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
irb(main):010:0> DateTime.parse("Fri, 08 May 2015 22:54:31 UTC +00:00").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
=> "08/05/2015"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this [`to_s`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-to_s) method alias of [`to_formatted_s`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-to_formatted_s) method.

```
your_var.to_s('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Visit [Strftime Rails api doc](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

```
t = Time.now                        #=> 2007-11-19 08:37:48 -0600
t.strftime("Printed on %m/%d/%Y")   #=> "Printed on 11/19/2007"
t.strftime("at %I:%M%p")            #=> "at 08:37AM"
```

Answer (score 0):

Althought all questions above work and do the job.I18n has a dedicated API for this.

> The rails way is described here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

**3.3 Adding Date/Time Formats**

```
<p><%= l Time.now, format: :short %></p>

# en.yml
en:
  time:
    formats:
      short: "%m/%d/%Y"
```

This helps keeps things clean and out of your views.

Hope it helps